# why i am getting null pointer exception inside contextInitialized() method while using Quartz job Scheduler

Tags: java, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler, jdbctemplate, servletcontextlistener

I am using quartz for scheduling the jobs, for that while initializing context i am doing database select opertion on database but it is giving null pointer exception.
while debugging it is not going in JobSchedulingDAOImpl class for select query.
How to resolve this issue so that it will perform select operation instead of giving null pointer exception.

Note : If i am not providing *jobsList =jobSchedulingDAO.getJobsList();* i am not getting null pointer exception. it is not going in getJobsList() method.

**Log details**

```
Launching defaultServer (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.7/wlp-1.0.10.cl50720150827-0437) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_60-b27 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server defaultServer has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0100I: This product is licensed for development, and limited production use. The full license terms can be viewed here: https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/license/base_ilan/ilan/8.5.5.7/lafiles/en.html
[ERROR   ] CWWKF0001E: A feature definition could not be found for servlet-3.1.0
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar can not be found in jar file file:/C:/Users/diwakar_b/.m2/repository/org/ehcache/ehcache/3.1.1/ehcache-3.1.1.jar or its parent.
[WARNING ] SRVE9967W: The manifest class path slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar can not be found in jar file file:/C:/Users/diwakar_b/.m2/repository/org/ehcache/ehcache/3.1.1/ehcache-3.1.1.jar or its parent.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://localhost:9080/ne/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application NormalizationEngine_ROAR-Dev started in 4.426 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0012I: The server installed the following features: [jsp-2.3, ejbLite-3.2, servlet-3.1, jndi-1.0, json-1.0, localConnector-1.0, jdbc-4.1, jaxrs-2.0, jaxrsClient-2.0, el-3.0].
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server defaultServer is ready to run a smarter planet.
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 06 15:43:30 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Registering annotated classes: [class com.hcl.ne.init.RootConfig,class com.hcl.ne.init.SecurityConfig]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'requestDataValueProcessor' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=requestDataValueProcessor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=requestDataValueProcessor; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration]
[err] ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/approve]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.ApproveController.getViewHistory(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/getStatus]}" onto public java.util.List<com.hcl.ne.model.DropdownMenu> com.hcl.ne.controller.CompanyController.getStatus()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/company]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.CompanyController.listCompany(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.hcl.ne.model.Company,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException,com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/newCompany],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.CompanyController.newCompany(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/company],methods=[POST],params=[saveCompany]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.CompanyController.saveCompany(com.hcl.ne.model.Company,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/editCompany],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.hcl.ne.model.Company com.hcl.ne.controller.CompanyController.editCompany(com.hcl.ne.model.Company,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/getDropdownVaues]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.List<com.hcl.ne.model.DropdownMenu>> com.hcl.ne.controller.CompanyController.getDropdownValues()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/configure]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.ConfigureController.getConfigureList(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/getstate]}" onto public java.util.List<com.hcl.ne.model.DropdownMenu> com.hcl.ne.controller.LocationController.getState(int)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/newLocation],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.LocationController.newLocation(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/location]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.LocationController.listLocation(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.hcl.ne.model.Location,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException,com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/getcity]}" onto public java.util.List<com.hcl.ne.model.DropdownMenu> com.hcl.ne.controller.LocationController.getCity(int)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/location],methods=[POST],params=[saveLocation]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.LocationController.saveLocation(com.hcl.ne.model.Location,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/editLocation],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.hcl.ne.model.Location com.hcl.ne.controller.LocationController.editLocation(com.hcl.ne.model.Location,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/login],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hcl.ne.controller.LoginController.loginPage()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/normalize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.NormalizeController.getViewHistory(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/parameters]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.ParametersController.getParametersList(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.hcl.ne.model.Parameters)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/parameters],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.ParametersController.saveOrUpdateParameters(com.hcl.ne.model.Parameters,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/productMapping]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.ProductMappingController.listCompany(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.hcl.ne.model.Company,java.lang.String,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws java.io.IOException,com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/rulesConfig]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.RulesConfigController.rulesConfig(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/console],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.console(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.list(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession) throws com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/getTimeZone]}" onto public com.hcl.ne.model.User com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.getTimeZone(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/getLocation]}" onto public com.hcl.ne.model.AjaxResponseBody com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.getLocationList(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/user]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.listCompany(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,com.hcl.ne.model.User,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException,com.hcl.ne.service.util.AppException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/addUser]}" onto public com.hcl.ne.model.AjaxResponseBody com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.getDropdownList(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.io.IOException
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/appConfiguration],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.appConfiguration(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/administration],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.administration(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/reports],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.reports(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/logout],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.logoutPage(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/addUser],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.addUser(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.hcl.ne.model.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/editUser],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.hcl.ne.model.User com.hcl.ne.controller.UserController.editUser(com.hcl.ne.model.User,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/viewHistory]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.hcl.ne.controller.ViewHisoryController.getViewHistory(org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,javax.servlet.http.HttpSession)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Sep 06 15:43:30 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5256 ms
Context Initialized
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.hcl.ne.jobs.QuartzListener.contextInitialized(QuartzListener.java:42)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:2389)
    at [internal classes]
```

**QuartzListener**

```
package com.hcl.ne.jobs;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobBuilder;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import org.quartz.TriggerBuilder;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import com.hcl.ne.dao.JobSchedulingDAO;
import com.hcl.ne.model.Jobs;

/**
 * @author diwakar_b
 *
 */
public class QuartzListener implements ServletContextListener{

    Scheduler scheduler = null;

    @Autowired
    private JobSchedulingDAO jobSchedulingDAO;
    List<Jobs> jobsList = null;


    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context) {
        System.out.println("Context Initialized");
        try {
            jobsList =jobSchedulingDAO.getJobsList();

            Iterator<Jobs> it = jobsList.iterator();
            if(it.hasNext()) {
                Jobs job = it.next();
                int jobScheduleTime = job.getJobScheduleTime();
                String jobName = job.getJobName();

                System.out.println(jobScheduleTime);
                System.out.println(jobName);
                JobDetail job1 = (JobDetail) JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("firstJob", "group1").build();

            }


            JobDetail job1 = (JobDetail) JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("firstJob", "group1").build();

            Trigger trigger1 = (Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("firstTrigger", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ? *"))
                    .build();

            JobDetail job2 = (JobDetail) JobBuilder.newJob(Job2.class).withIdentity("firstJob", "group2").build();

            Trigger trigger2 = (Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("secondTrigger", "group2")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ? *"))
                    .build();

            // schedule it
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

            scheduler.start();

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job2, trigger2);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        System.out.println("Context Destroyed");
        try {
            scheduler.shutdown();
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">


    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.hcl.ne.jobs.QuartzListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


</web-app>
```

**JbSchedulingDAO**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.hcl.ne.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.hcl.ne.model.Jobs;

/**
 * @author diwakar_b
 *
 */

@Repository
public interface JobSchedulingDAO {

    public List<Jobs> getJobsList();
}
```

**JobSchedulingDAOImpl**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.hcl.ne.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;

import com.hcl.ne.model.Jobs;
import com.hcl.ne.service.logging.AppLogger;

/**
 * @author diwakar_b
 *
 */

public class JobSchedulingDAOImpl implements JobSchedulingDAO {

    public JobSchedulingDAOImpl(DataSource dataSource) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }


    private final static AppLogger LOG = AppLogger.getLogger();
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    private List<Jobs> jobsList;

    @Override
    public List<Jobs> getJobsList() {
        String sql = "select * from ne_job_scheduling";

        LOG.info("Select Performed");

        jobsList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper<Jobs>() {

            @Override
            public Jobs mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                Jobs jobs = new Jobs();
                jobs.setJobId(rs.getInt("jobId"));
                jobs.setJobDetails(rs.getString("jobDetails"));
                jobs.setJobId(rs.getInt("jobName"));
                jobs.setJobId(rs.getInt("jobScheduleTime"));
                return jobs;
            }
        });

    return jobsList;
}}
```

**Updated QuartzListenerClass**

```
public class QuartzListener {

    @Autowired
    private JobSchedulingDAO jobSchedulingDAO;

    List<Jobs> jobsList = null;
    Scheduler scheduler = null;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initIt() {
      System.out.println("Init method after properties are set : ") ;

      try {
            jobsList =jobSchedulingDAO.getJobsList();

            Iterator<Jobs> it = jobsList.iterator();
            if(it.hasNext()) {
                Jobs job = it.next();
                int jobScheduleTime = job.getJobScheduleTime();
                String jobName = job.getJobName();

                System.out.println(jobScheduleTime);
                System.out.println(jobName);
                JobDetail job1 = (JobDetail) JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("firstJob", "group1").build();

            }


            JobDetail job1 = (JobDetail) JobBuilder.newJob(Job1.class).withIdentity("firstJob", "group1").build();

            Trigger trigger1 = (Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("firstTrigger", "group1")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ? *"))
                    .build();

            JobDetail job2 = (JobDetail) JobBuilder.newJob(Job2.class).withIdentity("firstJob", "group2").build();

            Trigger trigger2 = (Trigger) TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().withIdentity("secondTrigger", "group2")
                    .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 0/1 * * * ? *"))
                    .build();

            // schedule it
            scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();

            scheduler.start();

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job1, trigger1);

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job2, trigger2);

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: the context here is different @joc, anyway thanks.

Comment: a `NullPointerException` is always the same, read carefully and you will get your answer. Also....  as far as I can see, you don't provide `contextInitialized()` code or call....

Comment: @joc contextInitialized() method has been defined in QuartzListener class mentioned above,  i have gone through the link but unable to find the answer of my particular question here. while debugging in the line --jobsList =jobSchedulingDAO.getJobsList();-- in QyartzListener Class it is going in catch block, but every thig seems to be fine as far as code is concern. I am sorry but unable to find the appropriate answer while going while mentioned link. Is there a way to resolve the same.

Comment: Not sure if this works, but try adding a `@Component` annotation on `JobSchedulingDAOImpl `. From what I see, Spring is unable to wire up the repository, causing a null pointer exception

Comment: @SamuelKok I have already tried this but issue not resolved, Thanks though.

Comment: @joc we don't have to provide the call for contextInitialized(), spring automatically call this method while initailizing context by seeing the definition in web.xml(already defined the listener there)

Answer (score 1):

Your QuartzListener is not instantiated by Spring but by the container.

That's why the @Autowired is not 'interpreted'.

When the contextInitialized method is executed the dao hasn't been injected : NullPointerException.

You should move the code in QuartzListener into a spring bean and call it in @PostContruct method

Comment: Thanks, I have Tried this approach, but init() method is not even invoking here.I have update the code, please find it above.Is anything i have to done so that init method will invoke.

Comment: how are you registering your bean in spring ? With xml or annotation @Component + scan ?

Comment: I am using  <context:component-scan base-package="com.hcl.ne" />
but i am not using @Component, i have tried using it is giving error.
But i have define      '@Bean
     public JobSchedulingDAO getJobSchedulingDAO() throws AppException {
      return new JobSchedulingDAOImpl(getDataSource());
     }' in my rootConfi